# Quartz multiple independent Spring jobs to run together using same CRON expression

Tags: cron, spring-batch

I have multiple Spring batch jobs that I am required to schedule such that they are triggered at the same time.So far I am not having luck around this and I also do not under stand why.I read some where that having multiple jobs to trigger on same CRON expression(e.g. after every 10 mins) is not possible with Quartz and I have to increase the SIZE of the thread pool some how to make it possible.I just want to understand is this correct?If yes then is there an alternate way of achieving this sort of concurrency and if not then how can I increase the thread pool size in the xml configuration?Many Thanks in advance